# IBAction for each TableViewCell not returning unique NSIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

I'm attempting to segue to a user's profile screen when I tap on their username (see screenshot below). I have a `UITableViewController` with a feed of `UITableViewCell` that each have a `usernameLabel` (UILabel) and a transparent `userNameButton` (UIButton) positioned directly on top of the `usernameLabel` in order for the UILabel to be visible. The button acts like a 'hit area' essentially. I know I should probably just remove the UILabel and have the UIButton's text update to say the username, but that's a different story.

Here is my IBAction (Segue code isn't in here yet):

```
    @IBAction func usernameButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

       let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DrawingTableViewCell
       print("index path is: \(indexPath)")

       let cellsUsernameString = cell.usernameLabel.text

       print("just tapped the Feed username button for \(cellsUsernameString!)")

    }
```

Couple of questions:

1. My `usernameButtonPressed` is in my UITableViewController. Should I put this IBAction in the UITableViewCell's class? Or is it fine here?
2. The `indexPath` I print is exactly the same for each table cell. Why is this? Doesn't my `sender.tag` update to a different int value?
3. I think as a result of #2, each table cell is returning an incorrect username string.

Overall, my goal with this action is to get user (or object) info from the specific user for each respective tableview cell so that I can properly segue to that specific users profile. Obviously I will need more code to do this, but this is the beginning of my attempt at this and at this point I'm purely trying to obtain the correct username for each cell.

Here's a screenshot of the TableView in an attempt to provide more context:

[image]

Comment: Isn't it easier to connect the segue to the table view cell? Then you get the reference to the cell in `prepareForSegue`in the `sender` parameter and there is no need for a button. By the way: **never** call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. And you should get the user information from the model rather than from the view.

Comment: I could segue from tapping the entire table view cell, but the user may be confused on wether this action will take them to the drawing creator profile, or if it will take them to a separate view of just the drawing itself. Im trying to target the specific username to take them to that persons profile. Kind of like the Instagram app.

Re `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` - Thanks for that!

And getting user information from the model sounds like the correct way to go about it. I'm still pretty new to all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender tag will be the same for all your UITableViewCell because you are dequeuing the same custom cell.

You should subclass UITableViewCell and move your IBAction method into that subclass. You also need to change your cell class in storyboard to the new subclass.

You can declare a property in your UItableViewCell subclass with the same type you have in your data source and assign this property in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Then in the IBAction in your custom cell you segue to a user's profile screen and pass along the object or label text in your custom cell. You'll then get the destination view controller in prepareForSegue and assign this property to it.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks for describing it in simple, understandable terms for a noob like myself :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you should create a cell subclass and use that. Using tags is a poor technique and a subclass gives you an opportunity to provide a more appropriate interface. Either by setting the index path to be used, or by passing a block to be executed.

2 & 3. Unknown in a way, you haven't shown the code that sets it. But, most of the issue is that you're dequeuing a new cell instead of getting the current one. You should not dequeue new cells that you aren't going to use, you damage the table view cell cache. You also get an I configured cell...